# Outlook Email, installing to laptop

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How do I add my work email to my personal Surface Pro 3?

I can add my personal email accounts, but it won't let me add my work email account.  "We use Outlook at work, but when I try to install an Outlook email address, it says my email address does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If your email is on a Microsoft Exchange server you may not be able to connect to your email because your computer is not on your work domain.
You could also not be able to log in because you are not on your work network.  This can be fixed by using [Outlook Anywhere](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Outlook-Anywhere-to-connect-to-your-Exchange-server-without-VPN-ae01c0d6-8587-4055-9bc9-bbd5ca15e817?CorrelationId=b49fe8a7-c77f-4e15-9cd7-93e5b5e44c97&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

It is probably best if you can wait to talk to your company's tech department and see if there is anything specific you need to do to connect to their email system.